# How can I copy solely the values in this PHP array, not the structure?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

In php, I have an array, $OGarr, that prints to the error log:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [prop1] => 20
            [property2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [propertyIWant] => stringA
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [propertyIWant] => stringB
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I just want an array that has only the values [stringA,stringB]. I tried using a for loop, basically in C style:

```
$myNewArr = [];
for($x = 0; $x < $somenumber; $x++){
  $myNewArr[$x] = $OGarr[0]['property2'][$x]['propertyIWant'];
}
```

However, when I try to print $myNewArr, I get nothing. How can I get the array I need?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/SaXFP works fine.

Comment: @u_mulder can you elaborate, please? That link looks like spam.

Comment: This is a link to online php editor `3v4l`. Open it and see that provided code __works__.

Comment: as u_mulder said, your code work fine, can you please edit your code, and show us how $OGarr get the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
$ar = 
array(array('prop1'=>'20','property2'=>array(array('propertyIWant'=>'stringA'),array('propertyIWant'=>'stringB'))));

$result = array();

foreach($ar as $key=>$val){
     foreach($val['property2'] as $ex=>$v){
         $result[] = $v['propertyIWant'];
     }
}

print_r($result);

/***
 Array
 (
  [0] => stringA
  [1] => stringB
 )
**/
```

[Online Test](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b1FA)

Comment: I see $ar; what is $ar?